# How to install genymotion in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I have install genymotion in my PC but having problem with its plugin for eclipse. When i go to install new software and paste http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/ , the error become a=that is could not find http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/. I have done the installation of genymotion successfully once but this time it generate an error  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31148574/1466415), the Genymotion Eclipse plugin's repository seems to work. As a workaround you can get the plugin as a binary on [this page](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download#doc). Here is [the current direct link](http://plugins.genymotion.com/plugins/eclipse/1.0.4/plugins/com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.plugin_1.0.4.201503031034.jar).

[The documentation](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#genymotion-plugin-for-eclipse) explains how to install it manually and configure the Genymotion plugin on your IDE.