# How to plug genymotion for eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I have installed the genymotion in my computer and its working accuralty and now trying to plug for eclipse but its not working. According to instruction given in genymotion site as

1. In Eclipse, go to Help > Install new software and click Add.
2. Fill in the fields with Genymotion name and http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/ location.
3. Under Genymobile, check Genymotion and Genymotion Eclipse Tools and follow the steps indicated by Eclipse.

Step number 2 is not working. When i copy path and paste it then the it shows could not find http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/. 
So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After tests, the Genymotion Eclipse plugin's repository seems to work. As a workaround, you can get the plugin as a binary on [this page](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download#doc). Here is [the current direct link](http://plugins.genymotion.com/plugins/eclipse/1.0.4/plugins/com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.plugin_1.0.4.201503031034.jar).

[The documentation](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#genymotion-plugin-for-eclipse) explains how to install it manually and configure the Genymotion plugin on your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In the screen when you write the plugin link, UNCHECK the checkbox

**"Groups item by category"**

I hope it helps someone, I spent a good time with this.